# Pandas grouped on a numetric condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Here is my problem:

I have a dataframe on this forme :

```
name number 

A     2

B     10

C     25

D     35

E     45

F     55
```

and I want to group the name on numeric condition. In more details, I want to groupe by interval :

```
[0,15), [15,40), [40,+inf)
```

so I want the group

```
(A, B), (C, D), (E,F)
```

Do you know if it is possible to obtains that? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pandas.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) for new column or `Series`:

```
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['number'], bins=[0,15,40, np.inf], right=False, include_lowest=True)
print (df)
  name  number          bins
0    A       2   [0.0, 15.0)
1    B      10   [0.0, 15.0)
2    C      25  [15.0, 40.0)
3    D      35  [15.0, 40.0)
4    E      45   [40.0, inf)
5    F      55   [40.0, inf)

s = pd.cut(df['number'], bins=[0,15,40, np.inf], right=False, include_lowest=True)
```

And then use `groupby` with aggregation like:

```
df1 = df.groupby('bins').sum()
print (df1)

bins                
[0.0, 15.0)       12
[15.0, 40.0)      60
[40.0, inf)      100
```

Or use `Series`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(s).sum()
```

---

If want tuples:

```
s = pd.cut(df['number'], bins=[0,15,40, np.inf], right=False, include_lowest=True)

out = [tuple(x) for x in df.groupby(s)['name'].apply(list)]
print (out)
[('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('E', 'F')]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could always iterate over the dataframe and apply the conditionals. It's probably not the best solution but this should work:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df['number'][i] < 15:
        list1.append['name']
    if df['number'][i] >= 15 & df['number'][i] < 40:
        list2.append['name']
    if df['number'][i] > 15:
        list3.append['name']
```

hope this helps